# Collect real time rest API data and display it live on a graph in python

Tags: python, database, graph

I currently have a python GUI subscribing to and writing rest API data to a csv file. It also displays the cleaned up json output on a second window in real time. The data received from a camera is of a person walking along a road and consists of speed, direction, real world GPS coordinates as well as x and y coordinates relating to the camera position. The  x and y coordinates are part of the json output. I would like to display this x,y data as it is received in a scatter graph.
I am passing the live output to pandas, but not sure how to proceed to plot the data in metapltlib as scatter graph.
There might sometimes be more than one person in the picture that will provide 2,3 or 4 sets of coordinates. Is it possible to plot these as different colors on the scatter graph?

Here is my code to get the API data

```
Data = {
"messageType": "Subscription",
"subscription": {
    "type": "Data",
    "action": "Subscribe"
}
}
Event = {
"messageType": "Subscription",
"subscription": {
    "type": "Event",
    "action": "Subscribe"
}
}


# Connects to web socket
    def connect():
    ip_Url = "ws://" + ipEntry.get() + "/api/subscriptions"
    ws = create_connection(ip_Url)
    ws.connect(ip_Url)

sub = v.get()
    if sub == 'Data':
    ws.send(json.dumps(Data))

    if sub == 'Event':
    ws.send(json.dumps(Event))

while True:
    result = ws.recv()
    output = json.loads(result)
    c_data = pd.read_json(result)
    c_data.head()
    print(c_data)
    print("\n")

    # print output to file
    filename = "Cam " + sub + " API Output.csv"
    x = open(filename, "a")
    print(output, file=x)
    x.close()

ws.close()
```

This is my output data...

```
'dataNumber';'46366';'messageType';'Data';'time';'2022-02- 
 22T14:02:51.959+13:00';
'track';'angle';'62.00000000';'class';'Pedestrian';
'iD';'4075045';'latitude';'-36.75376913';'longitude';'174.70354402';
'speed';'1.25687909';'x';'0.35344221';'y';'3.91133603';
'type';'PedestrianPresenceTracking'
'dataNumber';'46366';'messageType';'Data';'time';'2022-02- 
22T14:02:51.959+13:00';
'track';'angle';'62.00000000';'class';'Pedestrian';
'iD';'4075045';'latitude';'-36.75376913';'longitude';'174.70354402';
'speed';'1.25687909';'x';'0.35344221';'y';'3.91133603';
'type';'PedestrianPresenceTracking'
'dataNumber';'46367';'messageType';'Data';'time';'2022-02- 
22T14:02:52.057+13:00'; 
'track';'angle';'62.00000000';'class';'Pedestrian'; 
'iD';'4075045';'latitude';'-36.75376888';'longitude';'174.70354435'; 
'speed';'1.10222912';'x';'0.38096526';'y';'3.94159039'; 
'type';'PedestrianPresenceTracking'
'dataNumber';'46367';'messageType';'Data';'time';'2022-02- 
22T14:02:52.057+13:00';
'track';'angle';'62.00000000';'class';'Pedestrian';
'iD';'4075045';'latitude';'-36.75376888';'longitude';'174.70354435';
'speed';'1.10222912';'x';'0.38096526';'y';'3.94159039';
'type';'PedestrianPresenceTracking'}
```

Here is the output from pandas

```
dataNumber  frameCounter  ...      time                        type
0           1313561 2629268  ... 2022-03-03T12:16:49.768+13:00 WorldData
1           1313561 2629268  ... 2022-03-03T12:16:49.768+13:00 WorldData
2           1313561 2629268  ... 2022-03-03T12:16:49.768+13:00 WorldData

[3 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, which means this question will probably be closed.  Do you want to the drawing yourself, in a GUI app?  Do you want to use `matplotlib`?

Comment: I was looking at matplotlib, but very new to python and working my way through it. Was thinking of adding all the data to a database like pandas and reading the database to plot the data automatically as it is received in a new window as part of the GUI. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it and how to do it? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: `pandas` uses `matplotlib` to do its plotting.  Based on the single hint `ipEntry.get()`, I'm guessing this is a `tkinter` app.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes this is correct. Tkinter as main gui. I would like to have the plot as a new window actvated with a button. I can create the button and window, just need assistance with the rest. The connection is run inside a tread to keep the main gui from freezing.